Program doesn't run anymore because I added await for page to be fully loaded function
My program runs a suite of actions. Between each action, there is a sleep(1000) that waits for the page to be fully loaded.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, _sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === 'triggerAction') {
        console.log('Triggering action');
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlToVisit }, (tab) => {
            console.log('TAB ID: ', tab.id);
            (async function () {

                for (let action of actions) {

                    console.log('ABOUT TO EXECUTE SCRIPT', action.type);
                    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                        {
                            target: { tabId: tab.id },
                            func: performAction,
                            args: [action]
                        }, () => {
                            console.log('Content script injected');
                        });
                    await sleep(1000); // 1 second pause

                }
                console.log('SCRIPT EXECUTED');
            })();
        })
    }
});

I wanted to replace this sleep with a listener that waits for the content of the page to be fully loaded. But it seems to be waiting indefinitely. So the suite of actions isn't executed anymore.
Here is the current version with the added listener:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, _sender, _sendResponse) => {
    if (message.action === 'triggerAction') {
        console.log('Triggering action');
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: urlToVisit }, (tab) => {
            console.log('TAB ID: ', tab.id);
            (async function () {

                for (let action of actions) {

                    await new Promise(resolve => {
                        chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                            {
                                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                                func: () => {
                                    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', resolve);
                                }
                            });
                    });


                    console.log('ABOUT TO EXECUTE SCRIPT', action.type);
                    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
                        {
                            target: { tabId: tab.id },
                            func: performAction,
                            args: [action]
                        }, () => {
                            console.log('Content script injected');
                        });

                }
                console.log('SCRIPT EXECUTED');
            })();
        })
    }
});


There's apparently a bug in Chrome and you need to wait for the tab to load between create() and executeScript as shown in this example (no need for setTimeout or DOMContentLoaded).

Is it possible that DOMContentLoaded is firing before your script is executed?
You could potentially try adding if (document.readyState !== loading) resolve(); just before your call to window.addEventListener
